# Proof that a block of digits doesn't repeat twice in a row in an irrational number in binary

Tags: number-theory, binary

So I've been trying to figure out this problem for 3 hours now and don't really know how to start.

What I'm trying to do is figure out if there is guaranteed to be, in an irrational number written in binary, a block of binary digits of length greater than once that repeats twice in a row
so for example:
$0.\underline{110}-\underline{110}$ has the block 110 twice. I know it's most probably true since I verified it using programming, unless something is wrong with my code, but I want to prove it without using the computer, to get some more insight about it.

What I've tried doing is write out all possible combinations for 4 digits and try out different combinations etc, I thought I'd have some idea well before I'm quarter way through combinations of a pair of 4 digit block, but that turned out not to be the case and there was a lot of wasted time on just trial and error.

I just don't know how to start on this one, any hints/ proofs would be very appreciated.

If needed I have studied a first course in number theory so I can understand that.

Comment: I'm not sure what "twice in a row" means here. Note that it's possible to construct an irrational number that avoids a particular pattern of digits just by building that into the definition of the number.

Comment: so for example 0.110110111 has 110 twice in a row buy 0.110111011 doesn't. you could define it and say it doesn't have such repititions but that could cause a contradiction if no such number does exist @Joffan

Comment: I'm still not sure though if you're searching for a given pattern, or just looking for an repeated set.  I should add that, in binary, it's not possible to construct an irrational number to avoid a given pattern of _two_ digits.

Comment: @Joffan yeah you could define it for a certain patter like that but can you define it so that nowhere in the text does a word of the form $a_1,a_2,...a+n,a_1,a_2,...a_n$ is formed anywhere in the binary number where $n\geq 2$. I am almost certain that no such number exists

Comment: OK, so you're looking for any repeat, not a given pattern - thanks. Probably worth clarifying that in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper "On nonrepetitive sequences" by Entringer and Jackson, in J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 11 (1974), 159–164. The link is
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316574900417,
the authors show that any binary sequence of length more than 18 must have two identical consecutive blocks, the length of which is at least 2.

The proof is by case analysis, shown in Figure 1 in the paper.

Comment: The proof is elegant. But, as per Math SE's standards, you should add the proof in the answer itself. Copy and paste, if you don't have the time.

Comment: I have no intention of figuring out how to copy and paste from a pdf. The proof of a result proved in a research paper needs no duplication, and I don't think such duplication is part of Math SE's policy.

Comment: @Aravind Good find. However, since it *is* a published paper, besides giving an url, you could also give the publication data, namely J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 11 (1974), 159–164. Also, while I see no need to copy the proof, I see no real objection to copy-pasting the abstract into your answer.

Comment: @Aravind You are looking at it the wrong way. If the proof is directly available in the answer, it would be much more suited for future visitors. They won't need to rely on external links. And, copying is as easy as selecting and Ctrl+C. :P

Answer (score 1):

You can deliberately define an irrational number to have this non-repeating quality, if required. For example, for an irrational number that avoids 3-blocks of repeating digits, take the binary definition of $\pi$ and generate a new number such that each digit $x$ in $\pi$ is replaced by $11x00$. (This also avoids 4-blocks).

To avoid any repetitions of whatever length, you would probably have to be more extravagant, coding further digits into ever larger strings (possibly using transforms of earlier digits). My expectation is that it is possible though.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question. So as to understand it, I have come up with a little puzzle. Could you write a sequence of 1s and 0s which is of length 12 and what I'll do is choose a starting point on that sequence and if I see that a block of digits is repeated twice in a row I'll tell you where it is. BTW thanks a lot for helping me out

Comment: @H_Hassan here are the first twelve post-radix digits of $\pi$: $001001000011$ and here is the modified version according to my construction: $110001100011100110001100011100110001100011000110001110011100$

Comment: look after the 15th digits comes $1100011000$ which is a repitition of $11000$ twice in a row

Comment: actually no need for that even, just take a look at the first 10 digits, they're a repitition of $11000$ twice in a row

Comment: @H_Hassan OK that's a 5-digit block repetition. So what you are saying then, I think, is that you are looking for any repetition of arbitrary length.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I mean, any idea on how I could prove that no number exists without such repititions